# Django filestorage save method creates path dependent on filename

Tags: python, django, django-file-upload

I am trying to work with a **filestorage** in Django. Everything is working fine but a thing in my save method I guess. I have a model with a `FileField`

```
download_url = models.FileField(verbose_name = 'Konfig', upload_to = file_path, storage = OverwriteStorage())
```

In this method in my model I create the `file_path`

```
def file_path(instance, filename):
        path = os.getcwd() + '/files'
        return os.path.join(path, str(instance.download_url), filename)
```

And the filestorage method I use is outsourced in my **storage.py** which I import in my models.py

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

class OverwriteStorage(FileSystemStorage):

    def _save(self, name, content):
        if self.exists(name):
            self.delete(name)
        return super(OverwriteStorage, self)._save(name, content)

    def get_available_name(self, name):
        return name
```

Now when I create a new file in the admin interface from django, it successfully uploads the file, makes a database entry with the correct filepath, but it fails to create the right path. When my filename is **foo** the path would look like following:

> cwd/files/foo/foo

and if its name would be **bar.txt** it would look like following:

> cwd/files/bar.txt/bar.txt

I don't want django to create a subdirectory based on the filename. Can you guys help me out ?

Comment: In that line `return os.path.join(path, str(instance.download_url), filename)` simply remove filename

Comment: My answer on your comment is too late, but yes that was right

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure you have to rename the save function from "save" to "_save".

On the Super Call, you used ._save, which isnt the same function as the save function above.

You can read alot about Super [here](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html#method-resolution-order)

Comment: I changed that now, but unfortunately that didn't bring the change